How do I find the shortcut ID?
I create a quick-firing XMB-style web-launcher for my PC, PS1, PS2 and Xbox 360 games via the corresponding method/emulator. I use AutoHotkey to handle creating the fullscreen window that shows a WebView with my launcher, then passing the JSON from AutoHotkey to the WebView with the game data (created by scanning my games folder). I wanted all of the Steam-external games like emulator ones to go through Steam so I've got the in-game overlay integration. I'm successfully using Node.js on my home server with 'steam-shortcut-editor' to modify my Steam's shortcuts.vdf file with all the games from my launcher.
I'm stuck at how shortcut IDs are generated or how I can find and extract them. Whatever is listed in the shortcuts.vdf file (whether the ID starts at 0 and increments, or if negative integers based around existing Steam-generated shortcuts are used) the actual ID of the shortcut when checked by their desktop shortcut is something totally different and seems to change even if the shortcuts entry is exactly the same. It's impossible to know the shortcut ID without manually creating the shortcut. The closest I feel I've got is to set the IDs to 0, 1, 2, etc. I noticed upon Steam startup each new shortcut has error messages like:
[2024-10-27 16:19:38] sanitize shortcut app id "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\duckstation\\duckstation-qt-x64-ReleaseLTCG.exe" -fullscreen -nogui "D:\\Games\\PlayStation 1\\Crash Bandicoot 2 - Cortex Strikes Back.bin": replacing 0 with 2260665730, reason: k_unAppIdInvalid
[2024-10-27 16:19:38] sanitize shortcut app id "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\duckstation\\duckstation-qt-x64-ReleaseLTCG.exe" -fullscreen -nogui "D:\\Games\\PlayStation 1\\Crash Team Racing.bin": replacing 1 with 3511852875, reason: k_unLocalAppIDFlag not set

But despite this the shortcut IDs are:
9709485377571520512
15083293246522130432

I've no idea how to calculate the IDs above. Even after creating the desktop shortcut it can be different each time Steam parses a shortcut file with fake IDs, even for the exact same game.

The shortcut ID to launch games is simply the unsigned 64-bit integer (appid << 32) | 0x02000000 where appid is the ID from shortcuts.vdf. The most significant 32 bits are the app ID and the least significant bits are the constant 0x02000000. You can read the app ID from shortcuts.vdf. Here's a Python script:
import re
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Tuple

def get_shortcut_id(appid: int):
    return (appid << 32) | 0x02000000

def get_non_steam_games(steam_config_path) -> List[Tuple[str, str, str, str]]:
    shortcut_path = steam_config_path / 'shortcuts.vdf'
    if not shortcut_path.is_file():
        print(f"No non-steam games shortcut file found at {shortcut_path}. Assuming no non-steam games are installed.")
        return []
    shortcut_bytes = shortcut_path.read_bytes()

    # Using regex to extract the shortcut information, rather than parsing it based on
    # the binary format
    game_pattern = re.compile(b"\x00\x02appid\x00(.{4})\x01appname\x00([^\x08]+?)\x00\x01exe\x00([^\x08]+?)\x00\x01.+?\x00tags\x00(?:\x01([^\x08]+?)|)\x08\x08", flags=re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    games = []
    for game_match in game_pattern.findall(shortcut_bytes):
        id = int.from_bytes(game_match[0], byteorder='little', signed=False)
        name = game_match[1].decode('utf-8')
        target = game_match[2].decode('utf-8')
        games.append((name, target, str(id), str(get_shortcut_id(id))))

    return games

print(get_non_steam_games(Path(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\<STEAM USER ID>\config')))

Steam will "sanitize" shortcuts if their app ID is not within the range allocated for non-Steam games. If you wanted to create a shortcut you could:

Add the shortcuts to shortcuts.vdf with random IDs.
Run Steam to let it sanitize the shortcuts.
Use the above process to get the shortcut IDs.

If you can figure out the acceptable range for non-Steam app IDs you can assign them within that range to skip steps 1 and 2.
